# C++ using Lapack within boost

Tags: c++, boost, lapack, boost-ublas

While developing a program i used frequently boost UBLAS types for matrices like hermitian_matrix and others.

I need to calculate eigenvalues and as i see UBLAS does not have something related with this. The first solution is to use LAPACK but i do not understand how to pass different UBLAS matrices types to a LAPACK library.

Are there any solutions instead of just converting UBLAS types into regular arrays and passing pointers?